# How to have a reference to a Constant but be able to change what the reference is pointing at?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012

I have a lot of C# Code that I have to write in C++. I don't have much experience in C++.

I am using **Visual Studio 2012** to build. The project is an **Static Library in C++** (not in C++/CLI).

**I have a class with some static instances that I want other classes to use**. I don't want anyone to be able to change the instances themselves, but I want the other classes to be able to use the different instances indistinctively.

What is the correct way to accomplish this in C++? Can I use references (&)? Do I have to use pointers? If I use Pointers, do I have to allocate my class with "new"? or can I use automatic allocation?

In case what I want is not clear, this code would theorically have what I want, but it doesnt build:

**C++ MyClas.h** // This is my class with static instances

```
class MyClass
{
private:
    std::string name;

public:
    MyClass(void);
    MyClass(string name);
    MyClass(const MyClass&);

    ~MyClass(void);
    std::string GetName(){return name;}

    static const MyClass& Instance1();
    static const MyClass& Instance2();
};
```

**C++ MyClas.cpp**

```
MyClas::MyClas(void)
{
}

MyClas::MyClas(string name)
{
    this->name = name;
}

MyClas::MyClas(const Unit& unit)
{
    name = unit.name;
}

MyClas::~MyClas(void)
{
}

const MyClas instance1= MyClas("Instance1");
const MyClas& MyClas::Instance1()
{
    return instance1;
}

const MyClas instance2= MyClas("Instance2");
const MyClas& MyClas::Instance2()
{
    return instance2;
}
```

How I would like to use it (this doesn't build though)

**c++ MyOtherClass.h** //This class uses MyClass instances

```
class MyOtherClass
{
protected:
    const MyClass& myInstance;

public:
    MyOtherClass(void);
    ~MyOtherClass(void);
    void Swap(const MyClass& myInstance);
};
```

**c++ MyOtherClass.cpp**

```
MyOtherClass::MyOtherClass(void): myInstance(MyClass::Instance1())
{
}

MyOtherClass::~MyOtherClass(void)
{
}

void MyOtherClass::Swap(const MyClass& instance)
{
    myInstance = instance; //Here it fails because I want to modify a const.
                            //I want to change my code so I only have 1 instance
                            //Instance1 and 1 Instance2 of MyClass, buy MyOtherClass
                            //can reference either without modifying them.
}
```

Comment: The name `Swap` should be avoided.  `std::swap` in C++ refers to taking two objects of the same type and swapping their internal state.  A method called `Swap` that does not have this meaning will just confuse things.

Comment: @Yakk thanks for the tip, I just put swap to signify what I wanted, but it is ont the actual name.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Do I have to use pointers?

Yes.

> I don't want anyone to be able to change the instances themselves

So you want a pointer to `const`, to prevent modification of the pointer's target object.

> do I have to allocate my class with "new"?

No, pointers can point to any object of a suitable type.

> or can I use automatic allocation?

Of course:

```
thing t1, t2;
thing const * p = &t1;  // points to t1
p = &t2;                // points to t2
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you have to use pointers.  No, you don't need dynamic allocation, or even automatic allocation.  Your current objects using static allocation have addresses too, which you get using the `&` address-of operator.

```
const MyClass* myInstance;

MyOtherClass::MyOtherClass(void): myInstance(&MyClass::Instance1())

void MyOtherClass::Swap(const MyClass& instance)
{
    myInstance = &instance;
}
```